# Ray cast doesn't validate hit in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Here I have results from `Intersection Line Plane` (green dot) and `Ray Cast` (red dot). White dots represent a *Line*.

I don't understand why does ray casting tell me **there is no hit**?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Ray Cast BVHTree* node takes a *Start* and a ***Direction***, not an *End*. To compute the ray direction vector from the line, you can subtract the start and end of the line to get the direction.

Comment: Actually, I was expecting hit where line intersects plane, so red dot should be where green is.

Comment: @SergeL Edited the answer.